# How to stop all Soundcloud streams in once?

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, soundcloud

Via the Soundcloud Javascript SDK I stream Soundcloud tracks via de SC.stream function. Multiple streams can be started but I want to stop the current streaming sound if another is started.

Is is possible to stop all streaming sounds via one function?

Answer (score 2):

Soundcloud creates a Soundmanager2 object for every stream you start. With the following function it is possible to stop all present and playing objects:

```
soundManager.stopAll();
```